# ImportError: Could not import settings - No module named settings

Tags: django

i have what seems to be a basic path problem, but i can't figure this out for the life of me.

I have the following directory structure:

```
    └── rockitt
        ├── activities
        │   ├── migrations
        │   ├── templates
        │   │   └── activities
        │   └── templatetags
        ├── blog
        │   ├── settings
```

within `blog/settings` I have:
`base.py  dev.py  __init.py__`

`__init.py__` within the directory above contains:
`from .dev import *`

When running things like manage.py i receive the following error:

`ImportError: Could not import settings 'blog.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named settings`

**What I have tried so far:**

1. I've checked what paths are present when manage.py is running and the following path is at the top of the list:

   `rockitt
   lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.7-py2.7.egg
   lib/python2.7
   [other dirs...]
   ENV/lib/python27.zip
   ENV/lib/python2.7
   ENV/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
   ENV/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
   ENV/lib/python2.7/lib-old
   ENV/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
   /usr/local/lib/python2.7
   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
   ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
2. I've tried to manually load the settings file with no luck:
   from the blog/settings directory i have tried (I'm not sure if this is the right way to test this however based on reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py):

   ```
   >>> import dev
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "dev.py", line 1, in <module>
       from .base import *
   ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
   ```

I'm kinda stuck on this. I -=think=- it might be also related to my wsgi.py file (below).

**Further info:**

1. wsgi.py:

   ```
   import os, sys, site
   site.addsitedir('/home/thisUserName/webapps/dev_django_rockitt/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "blog.settings.dev")
   activate_this =     os.path.expanduser("/home/thisUserName/webapps/dev_django_rockitt/ENV/bin/activate_this.py")
   execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

   #calculate the path based on the location of the WSGI script
   project = '/home/thisUserName/webapps/dev_django_rockitt/rockitt'
   workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
   sys.path.append(workspace)
   sys.path = ['/home/thisUserName/webapps/dev_django_rockitt/rockitt/blog', '/home/thisUserName/webapps/dev_django_rockitt/rockitt'$

   from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
   application = get_wsgi_application()
   ```
2. Stacktrace:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
     File "/home/thisUserName/webapps/dev_django_rockitt/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
     File "/home/thisUserName/webapps/dev_django_rockitt/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
   settings.INSTALLED_APPS
     File "/home/thisUserName/webapps/dev_django_rockitt/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.7-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
   self._setup(name)
     File "/home/thisUserName/webapps/dev_django_rockitt/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.7-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
   self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
     File "/home/thisUserName/webapps/dev_django_rockitt/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.7-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
   % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
   ImportError: Could not import settings 'blog.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named settings
   ```

Comment: Is the $ at the end of the sys.path line in wsgi.py just a copy-n-paste error?

Comment: it is - didn't catch the whole line - that's a small mistake compared to the idiocy (my own) i'm about to put in as the solution for me! good spot ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's almost tempting to remove this question due to my own stupidity, however i think the answer might help someone else who is coding and lacks sleep.

it's quite simple really - **it was a typo within the `blog/settings` directory**.

**I had typed `__init.py__`, but obviously it should have been `__init__.py`**

Once this was rectified the error disappeared.

I hope this helps someone in the future. Facepalm moment.

Comment: You should probably select this as the answer, as well.

Comment: "someone else who is coding and lacks sleep" thanks you.